# Molly Makeovers

Tags: the-dresden-files

Molly Carpenter goes through some changes in the last several (as of Mar 2017) Dresden Files novels. Specifically:

In *Changes*,

> she becomes traumatized by helping Harry to arrange his own death

Then, in *Ghost Story* ,

> she is living on the streets and makes even her family members nervous. I suppose it helps that Harry finds out about the memory wipe and she can work out the guilt over helping him arrange his death...

But, at the start of *Cold Days*,

> She has an apartment which she earned for helping the svartalves and she seems closer to herself.

Has Mr. Butcher written a story which details what Molly did between *Ghost Story* and *Cold Days* to improve herself  to get that apartment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "Bombshells", collected in *Dangerous Women* (2013; George R. R. Martin and Gardner Dozois, eds).  It's the story of the Svartalves' debt to Molly, told from Molly's point of view, and it explains the apartment.

It's also a substantial piece of character development.  The need to work with allies helps Molly to recover from her self-imposed isolation, and something she learns about Harry's situation gives her a renewed sense of optimism.